# Page set cognos Date field

Tags: cognos-10, dataitem

I need to create a Cognos report, the SQL query has data for last 3 months. I want 3 different report pages for each month. I have data items as date_insert which is datetimestamp field. I want all the dates with Jan month on page 1, Feb on page 2, and March on page 3. I have created data items with month and year with date_insert, and then applied page set on it, but it is not showing correct results. Please suggest.

Comment: Please provide the test data you have defined, your code so far, the actual output, and your desired output. I expect that we can help you if you provide this.

Comment: select a , hours(al1.Dateinsert) from table al1
WHERE (DATE(AL1.DTINSERT) >= (current_date - (day(current_date)-1) days - 2 month) AND DATE(AL1.DTINSERT) <= current_date - day(current_date)days).

Comment: Edit your question to include extra information, please.